# Android : How to Send a string over wi-fi without using printwriter?

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

The program here shows passing a string using wi-fi. I need a solution which does not require print writer or a simple solution which helps me send two different strings while toggling the buttons

```
switch3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (switch3.isChecked()) {
                messsage = "S";
                Log.d("On", "Button On" + messsage);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            // client = new
                            // Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                            client = new Socket("192.168.4.1", 100);

                            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client
                                    .getOutputStream(), true);
                            printwriter.write(messsage);
                            printwriter.flush();
                            //printwriter.close();
                            client.close();
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            } else {

                messsage = "T";
                Log.d("off", "Button off " + messsage);// etMsg.getText().toString();
                // etMsg.setText("");
                // port = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            // client = new
                            // Socket(etIP.getText().toString(), port);
                            //client = new Socket("192.168.4.1", 100);

                            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client
                                    .getOutputStream(), true);
                            printwriter.write(messsage);
                            printwriter.flush();
                            //printwriter.close();
                            client.close();
                        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data by this way ->

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(DESTINATION_ADDRESS, DESTINATION_PORT);
    // Exmp : Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 80);
    OutputStream outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
    out.writeUTF(SEND_STRING); 
    // Exmp : out.writeUTF("TEST");
    socket.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```